# R update select input values from csv file data values

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

KPIFile file will be uploaded by the users in the fileinput widget.

KPIFile has two column From and To. I am trying load the values of To column into the select input using updateselect input function. Its not loading the values from  column TO instead it loads some number.

```
# Loading the KPI data

KPI <- reactive({
    KPIFile<-input$KPI

    if(is.null(KPIFile))
      return(NULL)

     read.csv(KPIFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
             quote=input$quote)
    })


 #Loading the X and Y axis
 observe({

   updateSelectInput(session,"XVal", choices = KPI()[2])
   updateSelectInput(session,"YVal", choices =KPI()[2])


 })
```

Comment: Did my answer do the trick for you? If so, pleade accept!

Comment: No. Still I am getting  the random numbers. My Csv file content looks like as below. From To
EHRDKRS KB read/sec
EHRDKWS KB written/sec
EAAR Application Restarts
EAARu Applications Running
EAAA App Availability
EAMA Machine Availability.
OAPWECPM EHL Calls/Min

Comment: Please include the whole csv

Answer (score 1):

Without the `csv` file which is giving you trouble it is hard to say what is going wrong. My guess is that `R` is converting the column to a [factor](https://www.google.com/search?q=factor%20r&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

To prevent that, use `stringAsFactors = FALSE` in your functions to read the `csv` file

```
read.csv(KPIFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
         quote=input$quote, stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Or convert it afterwards with

```
 yourDataFrame$columnYouNeedToRead <- as.factor(yourDataFrame$columnYouNeedToRead)
```

or (which is the same)

```
library(magrittr)
yourDataFrame$columnYouNeedToRead %<>% as.character
```

Comment: @VinothLoganathan That good to hear. If you like the answere please accept it :) Thats how SO works